# State-space models with latent variables in R

Tags: r, bayesian, kalman-filter, rstan

I tried to estimate State-space models with latent variables in r, but I failed. 
I tried to do it in rstan package. 
Does someone know how to do it better?

Let's say we have two observable variables: gdp and inflation.
We also know there are three unobservable variables: potential grow, potential gdp, output gap.
We want to estimate unobservable variables and two coefficient (a1 and a2).

**Our model:**

State Equations:

- grow[t] = grow[t-1] + e
- potential[t] = potential[t-1] + grow[t] + e
- gap[t] = a1*gap[t-1] + e

Measurement Equations:

- gdp[t] = potential[t] + gap[t]
- inflation[t] = inflation[t-1] + a2*gap[t] + e

**Here I generated data:**

```
a1 <- 0.7
a2 <- 0.3

grow <- c()
potential <- c()
gap <- c()
gdp <- c()
inflation <- c()

grow[1] <- 2
potential[1] <- 10
gap[1] <- 0
gdp[1] <- potential[1] + gap[1]/100
inflation[1] <- 2

for (i in 2:100) {
  grow[i] <- grow[i-1] + rnorm(1, 0, 0.1)
  potential[i] <- potential[i-1] + grow[i]/100 + rnorm(1, 0, 0.1)
  gap[i] <- a1*gap[i-1] +  rnorm(1,0,0.1)
  gdp[i] <- potential[i] + gap[i]/100
  inflation[i] <- inflation[i-1] + a2*gap[i]   + rnorm(1,0,0.1)
}
```

**And here is my rstan code:**

```
data {
  int T; // number of obs
  int P; //number of variables
  matrix[T,P] Y; //dataset of generated series
}

parameters {

  #Coefficients
  vector[1] alfa1; //ar gap
  vector[1] alfa2; //phillips curve

  #State Variables (unobserved economic variables)
  vector[T] gap; // output gap
  vector[T] potential; // potential output
  vector[T] grow; // growth of potential output

  #Innovations
  real<lower = 0> sigma_pot; // The scale of innovations to potential output
  real<lower = 0> sigma_grow; // The scale of innovations to growth in potential output
  real<lower = 0> sigma_gap; // The scale of innovations to output gap
  real<lower = 0> sigma_inf; // The scale of innovations to phillips curve
}


model {
  // priors

  //Innovations
  sigma_pot ~ cauchy(0.2,3);
  sigma_grow  ~ cauchy(0.3,3); 
  sigma_gap ~ cauchy(0.9,5); 
  sigma_inf ~ cauchy(2,5);

  //coefficients
  alfa1 ~ normal(0,1); 
  alfa2 ~ normal(0,1); 


  //Initialize State Equations
  potential[1] ~ normal(0,1);
  grow[1] ~ normal(0,1);
  gap[1] ~ normal(0,1);

  // State Equations
  for(t in 2:T) {
    grow[t] ~ normal(grow[t-1], sigma_grow);
    potential[t] ~ normal(potential[t-1] + grow[t], sigma_pot);
      gap[t] ~ normal( alfa1*gap[t-1], sigma_gap);
  }

  // Measurement Equations
  for(t in 1:T) {
   Y[t,1] = potential[t] + gap[t];
     Y[t,2] ~ normal(Y[t-1,2] + alfa1*gap[t],sigma_inf);
  }
}
```

**Here I tried model**

```
mvf_model <- stan(file = "newstan.stan" , 
                  data = list(T = nrow(data),
                              P = ncol(data),
                              Y = data),
                  chains = 4)
```

**And here is the error I've got**

```
Cannot assign to variable outside of declaration block; left-hand-side variable origin=data
Illegal statement beginning with non-void expression parsed as
  Y[[t, 1]]
Not a legal assignment, sampling, or function statement.  Note that
  * Assignment statements only allow variables (with optional indexes) on the left;
  * Sampling statements allow arbitrary value-denoting expressions on the left.
  * Functions used as statements must be declared to have void returns

 error in 'model16a4a72378d_newstan' at line 27, column 3
  -------------------------------------------------
    25: transformed parameters {
    26:  for(t in 1:T) {
    27:    Y[t,1] = potential[t] + gap[t];
          ^
    28:   }
  -------------------------------------------------

PARSER EXPECTED: "}"
Error in stanc(file = file, model_code = model_code, model_name = model_name,  : 
  failed to parse Stan model 'newstan' due to the above error.
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that you cannot assign a function of parameters to something declared in the data block because things in the data block are immutable. I'm not entirely sure what you were trying to do. Do you have observed data when `t = 1` or not?

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for your time!   Yes, I have observed data in t=1 except for the latent variables.  I was trying to set the measurement equation: " gdp[t] = potential[t] + gap[t]  " .   Where gdp is observable, and potential and gap are not observable.

Comment: I think you need something like `gdp[1] ~ normal(potential[1] + gap[1], sigma_inf / (1 - ?))` followed by a loop from `t = 2` to `T`. The question mark is that you need to figure out what to divide the _conditional_ (on the lagged value of `Y`) standard deviation of the errors, `sigma_inf`, by in order to get the _unconditional_ (i.e. not conditional on the lagged value of `Y`) standard deviation of the errors.

Comment: Thank you, Ben! But what if I want 'gdp' to be exactly 'potential' + 'gap'. Without any error.  So it's more like a constraint. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Then declare `gdp_1` as a transformed parameter and don't condition on the first observed value of GDP. But it doesn't make sense to say that GDP has no error in period 1.